# Customer is active even after session deleted

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-session, soap-api-v2, logout

I have a simple service, SOAP API, to log out customer based on his email ID.

This service is getting parameter properly and even the respective user session is deleted. I have confirmed this using the system logs.

But the issue is Customer is still not logged out from the system.

Can someone please help, since I am newbie in Magento.